# Pivot dataframe with R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

What I would like:
[image: What I would like]

What I have:
[image: What I have]

I have a dataframe with a lot of rows with a column for the ID (several letters). The others columns are corresponding to different characteristics of the item which is informed in the ID column. The names of the columns are composed by letters and "-" and the information in this columns are only letters.

I would like to change the organization of my dataframe to fit with the second picture with utilization of R language.

I think that I should use pivot but I search and I don't find the correct one. I hope that someone can help me please.

Comment: Please share your sample input and desired output as copy/pasteable text. We can't test code on a picture of data. `dput()` is great for creating copy/pasteable code to recreate data, e.g. `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows of `your_data`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is not recommended to have space in column names, they should not start with a number.

```
library(tidyverse)
matrix(data = c("s1", "1.1.1", NA, NA, 
                            "s1", "1.1.2", NA, NA, 
                            "s1", NA, "1.2.1", NA, 
                            "s1", NA, "1.2.2", NA, 
                            "s1", NA, NA, "1.3.1",
                            "s1", NA, NA, "1.3.2"), nrow = 4) %>% 
      t() %>%
      as_tibble() %>% 
      dplyr::rename(ID = V1, info_1 = V2, info_2 = V3, info_3 = V4) %>% 
      
  # Solution
  gather(info, value, -ID) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  separate(info, into = c("info", "cat_info"), sep = "_") %>% 
  group_by(cat_info) %>% 
  mutate(row_count = row_number()) %>% 
  unite(info_number, info, row_count) %>% 
  spread(info_number, value)
```